# Mirror and flip objects with mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I have a environment that is mirrored and flipped along the world origin. I placed an Empty object at the world origin and applied a Mirror modifier for the objects to get mirrored along the Y axis, but I can't get them to flip along the X axis too.

**Here's what I'm looking for:**
[image: result im looking for]

**Here's what I'm getting:**
[image: result im getting]

How can I achieve this mirror + flip result?

Comment: @MrZak that would make four copies of a single object. The objects in the image aren't the same.

Comment: Then the simplest solution would be using Interactive mirror tool based on 3d cursor. Up until 2.79 it was mapped to Ctrl+M. Note though that it inverts scale thus when applying normals get flipped. Another solution could be using Array modifier with Object offset set to that empty (circular array basically). Though the origin point of objects has to be set to empty

Comment: @MrZak so it's not possible to do by only using modifiers without moving the origin of each object?

Comment: It is generally possible with Array set to both Object and Constant (or Relative) Offset. Object offset will move to the center, constant offset will move to place. However this way requires coordinates for Constant / Relative offset, e.g if your object is at X -5, Y 5 then offset should be at X 5 Y 5 like https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k10Z.jpg

Answer (score 1):

What you actually are doing is rotating the object 180 deg in the Z axis.
You can do that procedurally with an array modifier and an empty rotated 180 degrees.

Comment: That way the object appears at the same place as the Empty object. How can I keep the distance from the Empty the same?

Comment: Or are you assuming the origin of the object is at the world origin?

Comment: @Tiago Exactly, place the objects origin at the world location. Otherwise you will have to use two empties at the exact target positions.